# "Add comment" link is not there on my question

Tags: support

Hello all,

recently i have asked a question on "Electronic gadgest -beta" but overthere one answer is received: http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/android-update-to-sdk-2-2/1596#1596 ,

but i want to add comment to that answer, but get shocked becoz overthere **`"add comment" link is not there`**, why this ?

see the below image:

[image]

Comment: It's there for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it:
[image: Pic of the button]

Comment: @Jinguy sorry! still not for me..i think its broken or somewhere bug

Comment: @Paresh, do a 'hard refresh' (ctrl+f5).  See if it is still missing.

Comment: @Jinguy after logging-out and then again log-in, it is showing up thanx

Answer (score 1):

This may sound really silly, but are you certain you're still logged in? I see what's in your screenshot, but I am not logged in (and don't have an account, anyway). Could that be it?

Comment: Checking [your user profile](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/users/1018/), it says you haven't been on Gadgets since 3 hours ago, while your screenshot indicates you're looking at it much more recently. This actually sounds more plausible than I gave myself credit for, initially.